# Project files are not imported after importing the project in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am new to scala as well as Eclipse. Please be smooth on my question. I looked mostly on all available resources of eclipse.

I am using Scala IDE in Eclipse. When I am importing the project into Eclipse(General->Import Existing Project...), then the project is imported, but main files in src/ as well as in test/ are not imported and they are present in project directory.

Here is the screenshot of the eclipse. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

**main/** and **test/** are empty, but they contains the project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though source and class path resources may reside with the src/main/scala and src/test/scala folders under your project on the file system, Eclipse separates them off in the Package Explorer view and shows them in a separate part of the tree decorated with a little package icon.

See the first item in the tree under progfun-example.

Hopefully your source will be there. (The presence of the tree expansion toggle icon would indicate that there is something there.)